# Get Primary gmail id among all gmails in my mobile

Tags: java, android, email, android-intent, gmail

we have one requirement, to display primary Gmail account in edittext. But i am getting all email(Gmail) accounts which are logged in my mobile.

I am using below code.

```
Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
                Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(MainActivity.this).getAccountsByType("com.google"); 
                if(accounts.length>1){
                    for (Account account : accounts) {
                        if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
                            String possibleEmail = account.name;
                            Log.d("email::","email::"+possibleEmail+"----"+account.type);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.d("email::","email::no mails found");
                }
```

Please help me to find out the primary email id.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try This:-

```
private String getEmailID() {
        AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
        Account[] list = manager.getAccounts();

        for (Account account : list) {
            if (account.type.equalsIgnoreCase("com.google")) {
                gmail = account.name;
                break;
            }
        }

        mStr_email = gmail;
        Log.d(KEY_TAG, "EMAIL" + mStr_email);

        return mStr_email;
    }
```

Code to Check whether Internet Connection is On:-

```
 InternetConnection  ic = new InternetConnection(getApplicationContext());
            isInternetPresent = ic.isConnectingToInternet();
            if (!isInternetPresent) {

                Utilities.showToast(SplashActivity.this,
                        "Switch on Internet Connection");
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
            } else {
                Log.d(KEY_TAG, "Check attendane ");
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, here what is the attendance();? And also i didnot get primary email. only got the top most email among all emails. :(

Comment: Its working, But i want to know among all emails which one is primary. How can i find out among all. Your solution gives only top email id.You have any idea how to find primary email ?